# Microsoft Edge not opening local websites

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

For development purposes I use many *fake* domains from my hosts file and creating virtual hosts.

Using Microsoft Edge, I can't open any of my local domains from hosts files

Is there anything I can do to solve this issue? I have searched many times without any clues

[image]

P.S: I can open http://localhost/ and http://127.0.0.1/ without problem

Comment: did you get around this issue? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I will base my answer to the problem title. Did you turn on your XAMPP? I don't know if your using code igniter to get through of the localhost as what I've seen in your sample picture.
.
I experience this before, what I did is, open any browsers. Then type localhost/xampp once loaded by that browser copy that one the url to Microsoft Edge either of the two fields. It will work.
.
[image: xampp]

For the project - localhost/projectName
[image: project file]

Sorry for the bad quality pictures. But for visual aid only.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this is not the issue I'm having here

Comment: unfortunately not :(